# Bayes' rule for conditional expectations (Proof review)

Tags: probability, numeraire

> The Baye's rule for conditional expectations states
>
> $$ E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]E^P[f|\mathcal{F}]=E^P[Xf|\mathcal{F}] $$
>
> With $f=dQ/dP$ - thus being the Radon-Nikodyn derivative and $X$ being
>   some random variable and $\mathcal{F}$ being some sigma-algebrad.

For I wasn't able to find the proof in any of the books that I usually use I tried to prove it myself. This rule is **often used in the context of the change of numeraire technique**.

The proof uses the definition/characterization of conditional expectations. Thus one mainly needs to show

$$\int_A E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]E^P[f|\mathcal{F}]dP=\int_AE^P[Xf|\mathcal{F}]dP $$ 
For all $A\in\mathcal{F}$

Again using the characterisation of conditional expectation the right side  equals $\int_A Xf dP$ and with $f$ being the Radon-Nikodyn-derivative this is equal to $\int_A X dQ$ thus

$$\int_AE^P[Xf|\mathcal{F}]dP=\int_A X dQ $$

On the other side using measurability of $E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ the left side equals
$$\int_A E^P\left[(E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}] f)\vert \mathcal{F}\right] dP$$
Once again using the characterisation of conditional expectation this is
$$\int_A E^P\left[(E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}] f)\vert \mathcal{F}\right] dP=\int_A fE^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]  dP$$
Finally with $f$ being the Radon-Nikodyn density one arrives at

$$\int_A fE^Q[X|\mathcal{F}] =\int_A E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}] dQ=\int_A X dQ$$
and thus 
$$\int_A E^Q[X|\mathcal{F}]E^P[f|\mathcal{F}]dP=\int_A X dQ$$

This concludes the proof.

**Two question:**

- does anyone know of a source where I could cross-check that
- is there an alternative way to proof the result ?

Comment: The book "Statistics of Random Processes" Vol. 1 by Robert Lipster and Albert Shiryaev has a whole chapter devoted to various (abstract) forms of Bayes Law. If I remember correctly it is chapter 7. The eBook is available from SpringerLink if you have access.

Comment: thank you for the reference  - seeing how it also answers my question - you can post it as an answer not only as a comment - the reference might be interesting to others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this the proof you are looking for?

[image]

-- from Shreve, S. E.'s book "Stochastic calculus for finance II, continuous-time Models", chapter 5.

Comment: thanks - hopefully that also comprehensively clarifies your numeraire question

Comment: athos, is this correct? https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22268/

Answer (score 1):

$$
\def\Filtr{\mathcal{F}}
\def\EF{E^\Filtr}
$$
Let $f=dQ/dP$, and denote by $E$, $E_Q$ the expectation
with respect to the measure $P$, $Q$, respectively.
Let us also write $\EF$, $\EF_Q$ instead of
$E(\cdot|\Filtr)$,
$E_Q(\cdot|\Filtr)$.

Assume that all random variables listed below are integrable,
in particular, that $E|\xi|$, $E|f\xi|$, $E|f^2\xi|<\infty$.
Let $\Filtr$ be any $\sigma$-field.

Thanks to self-adjointness property of conditional expectation ($E(\xi\EF\eta)=E(\eta\EF\xi)$), we have for every $A\in\Filtr$:
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\eqby}[1]{\stackrel{\text{#1}}{=}}
E(\xi f\EF(f1_A)) &= E(f1_A\EF(\xi f)),\\
E_Q(\xi\EF(f1_A)) &= E_Q(\EF(\xi f)1_A),\\
E_Q(\xi(\EF f)1_A) &= E_Q(\EF(\xi f)1_A),\\
\EF_Q(\xi\EF f) &\eqby{a.s.} \EF\xi f,\\
(\EF f)(\EF_Q\xi) &\eqby{a.s.} \EF\xi f.
\end{align*}
Second equality follows from the definition of $f$,
third from the pull-out property
($\EF\xi\eta=\xi\EF\eta$, if $\xi$ is $\Filtr$-measurable)
and from $\Filtr$-measurability of $1_A$,
fourth from the definition of conditional expectation $\EF_Q$,
and the last one by the pull-out property,
as $\EF f$ is already $\Filtr$-measurable.